# shopware failed to generate key

Tags: php, key, shopware

On shopware setup, system requirments i get message "All of the requirements for successful installation have been met." as shown on image below.
[image]

But after clicking next btn i get error, failed to generate key, as shown below...
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell, the error is coming from `openssl_pkey_new` due to a failure on creating a new cert, it's better to ask the package maintainers

Comment: Is it maybe that i am doing this on Windows os?

Comment: There is a comment on the `openssl_pkey_new` manual on PHP that mentions a specific config for Windows, so yes, this maybe the issue.

Comment: I gave up on this, and installed shopware with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ensure the OpenSSL extension for PHP is installed and enabled by checking `php.ini` & `phpinfo()`. you can then check this as well `extension_loaded('openssl')`. check permissions, and examine error logs